# Azure server farm, route by sub-domain, same codebase

Tags: azure

I'm a total newb when it comes to server farm setup, but I do know what I want to do, and have good reasons for it, just not sure how to do it.

I have one codebase (a web app) which I want to run on multiple servers (possibly 100s).  I want a 1 to 1 mapping of sub-domains to servers, so I have 100% control over which traffic goes to which server.

When I say "server" I think I mean "instance" as I don't care if they are physical or virtual servers (should be transparent to my design and work either way).

How can I set this up for easy maintenance and easy adding/removing of servers?  I already have my app setup with a database of servers, population/load info for each server, routing, and all of that fun... so I don't need help on the app/programming part, just the Azure setup/maintenance part.

**More Info:**

In case it helps find an easy answer, but still trying to keep this a general topic (hopefully not too specific to my exact needs, I feel this is a common scenario).

My specifics are an MMO board game.  Each game is self-contained (no cross game communication/stats/etc).  Each game cannot contain over 100 active players at a time.  A single server might handle 1 to 100 games, but all players for each game need to be connected to the same server.  The server will keep all of the game info in memory only (fine if a recycle restarts a game, games don't last that long and not a big deal if players restart).  All servers/instances will have the exact same game code deployed.

I will have a login server, or possibly multiple, this detail doesn't matter too much.  All the login server needs to do is decide which server to send the player to, based on their login info and which game they want to join.  To "send" the player to that server, the login server will redirect them to a subdomain.. such as "server1.mydomain.com", "server2.mydomain.com", etc.

Thus, I think my general, and possibly simple question still stands... I just want to be able to route traffic to different servers based on subdomains, AND have all of those servers share the same codebase.  I know ways I can do this, but not sure what is easy/good with Azure.  I'm currently trying a method where I deploy updates from a git repo, hosted on Visual Studio online, which does at least keep the codebase sync'ed up between multiple web apps.  However, it takes 30+ minutes to deploy each update (takes about 10 minutes to rebuild on each server, times 3 servers I'm currently using)... if I end up with 30+ servers, that could be really slow.

Answer (score 1):

If you're goal is to have a simple mapping of servers to sites, then this is simply a scripting / programming problem.

You would need to automate the deployment of a server and a corresponding sub domain. All of this can be done through Azure. You can deploy a server and configure DNS to point to its corresponding IP Address.

Probably the simplest method would be to create an Azure Resource Manager template, which will create your azure configuration, including any server setup needed, then fire this off with either Powershell, or the Azure commandline tools. As ARM Templates aren't able to configure DNS yet, you would need to script that aspect.

Ultimately you'd have a script that read through your database and for each entry went off and created a server, installed whatever needed installing, configured DNS then repeated the process for the next.

However, I suspect there might be an easier way to achieve you goal, for instance you might be able to load up a single server with hundreds of sub domains, and have the server decide what goes where. But we would need more information on your desired result before being able to comment further.

Comment: The easy route you mention might be possible is what I suspect I'm missing.  Although if I had any idea on how to create the automated scripts that might be great too.  As far as figuring out if there is something easy, are there any particular questions I can answer, or how can I improve my question?

Comment: I added a bunch more info.. hopefully not too much.